# PHP version if 5.6 but PEAR says it's 5.5. How do I get PEAR on 5.6?

Tags: php, version, pear

Not sure what to do... PHP is on 5.6, but PEAR saying the PHP version is 5.5 so when I install a PEAR package, it goes to a location that is the wrong include path (a 5.5 pear include path), so when I include things my code can't find it because it's looking in the 5.6 pear include path.

I think the solution is either to get pear to use php version 5.6 or downgrade my php version to 5.5 but I'm wondering if there's a way to tell pear to use 5.6 easily?

```
[test@main html]$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.5.38
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux classified 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 24 14:31:22 UTC 2017 x86_64

$ php --version
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2017 20:51:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: There are many reasons why this happens. I suggest to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) instead of Pear.

Comment: What are some common reasons?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the php version that pear is using.

```
$ pear config-get php_bin
/usr/bin/php

$ pear config-set php_bin /path/to/php
```

Unfortunately, PEAR is still using the old version because it's hard-coded in the `pear` shell script. Open it and edit the path.

```
$ emacs `which pear`
...
PHP="/usr/bin/php"
```

Change that line.

The PEAR installer now will have picked up the new PHP version, and probably a different directory for the installation of .php files:

```
$ pear config-show
...
php_dir /path/to/dir
```

You probably have to reinstall the packages to move them to the new directory.